# Two points :A and B are picked randomly (uniformly) on [0,1] independent of one another. What is the expected value of length AB?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation

> Two points :A and B are picked randomly (uniformly) on [0,1] independent of one another. What is the expected value of length AB?

E[A]=E[B]= $\frac12$ since A,B ~ U(0,1)

Now using conditional expectation:

$E[AB]=E[E[AB|E[A]=E[B]]$

This is where I'm confused. Why aren't we integrating $\frac{1}{4}$ from 0 to 1?

I'd appreciate some insight as to why the solution is $\frac{1}{3}$ and not $\frac15$

Comment: Here's a brief answer. Intuitively, this length is equal in distribution to the length from one end (the zero end) to the first point (the shorter of A and B). I'm assuming you covered Beta distributions. This follows a Beta(1,2) distribution. The expectation is 1/3.

Comment: No Beta distribution, just he basic geom/exp/bin/norm/uniform. What's an

Comment: I assume you mean an**swer**. It's 1/3.

Comment: @Max meant to say what's an explanation without the Beta distribution using conditional probability?

Comment: Do you mean area? I do not understand what you mean by "length $AB$". I would think that $A$ and $B$ are two lengths that become multiplied to form something that can be visualized as an area?

Answer (score 2):

$\int_{x=0}^1 \int_{y=0}^1 |x-y| dx dy = 2\int_{x=0}^1 \int_{y=0}^x (x-y) dx dy = 2\int_{x=0}^1 {x^2 \over 2} dx = {1 \over 3}$.